# mobilize SAP using SUP

Tags: ios, objective-c, sybase, sup

I am an iOS developer. I am planning to do some sap back ended applications for iOS. when I Googled this, I realized that sybase has released sybase unwired platform(SUP) to mobilize the SAP.

I have few questions to explore regarding SUP:

1. What is the benefit of SUP when compared to another approach?
2. Is it possible to mobilize a big size SAP application also?
3. Should I need to do any special modification in SAP for this SUP?
4. Whether any other similar unwired platforms available in the market? If any please give some detail of it.

If anyone knows SUP Please direct me on the right path to explore.

Answer (score 2):

1. Compared to which other approach? SUP make pretty easy accessing functionalities, reading data from and writing data to a SAP backend.
2. Yes, if you are willing to recode all screens for iOS. As far as I know SUP let you mobilize data and functionalities (if they are webservices or RFC's), but not a whole application without a frontend effort.
3. It will depend on how it was coded on the SAP backend. If you have RFC's for all of your needed functionalities, then you won't have to change anything.
4. I'm not aware of any, but take a look at SAP Project Gateway, which is more focused on small applications communicating through REST-based webservices with SAP backend.

If you want to learn SUP, check this [SDN videos](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/bpx/index?rid=/webcontent/uuid/50df5be0-245a-2e10-a8a5-a3b00f9eb4be), and the [Sybase Infocenter](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.pubs.docset-SUP-2.0.0/doc/html/title.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called SAP Netweaver Gateway in the ramp-up-process (like a beta for a couple of customers) that simplifies the access to SAP data via Rest Web Services (oData).  Maybe you should investigate in this topic also.

Do you need to deploy to several devices?